# How to convert an array of array into a matrix?

Tags: julia

Suppose I want to apply a vector-valued function `phi` to a vector `x`:

```
phi(x, d) = [x.^i for i=0:d]    # vector-valued function
x = rand(7)                     # vector
y = phi(x, 3)                   # should be matrix, but isn't
```

Now `y` should be a matrix, but it is an `4-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`, i.e. an array of arrays.  Actually, I want `y` to be a matrix.  Is the implementation of `phi` wrong?  Or how do I convert it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you noted, you can concatenate an array of arrays `x` using `hcat(x...)`, but it's usually better to create a matrix to begin with instead. Two ways that you can do it in this case:

1. Using broadcasting:

   ```
   phi(x, d) = x.^((0:d)')
   ```

   As long as `x` is a vector, it will broadcast against the row matrix `(0:d)'`.

   You can get the transpose result by transposing `x` instead of the range `0:d`.
2. Using a two-dimensional array comprehension:

   ```
   phi(x, d) = [xi.^di for xi in x, di in 0:d]
   ```

   This will work as long as `x` is iterable. If `x` is an n-d array, it will be interpreted as if it were flattened first.

   You can transpose the result by switching the order of the comprehension variables:

   ```
   phi(x, d) = [xi.^di for di in 0:d, xi in x]
   ```

Answer (score 20):

Converting `phi`'s output to a matrix can be done as follows:

```
   y = hcat(phi(x, 3)...)
```

or if you prefer the vectors to be rows, a transpose is needed:

```
   y = vcat([x' for x in phi(x, 3)]...)
```

Alternatively, you can convert to a matrix within `phi` by defining it:

```
   phi(x, d) = hcat([x.^i for i=0:d]...)
```

Answer (score 11):

More generally you can also use the splat operator `...` with `hcat`:

```
X = [[1,2], [3, 4], [5,6]]
hcat(X...)
```

gives a 2-by-3 matrix

```
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to splatting like `hcat(X...)` is to use `reduce`

```
reduce(hcat, X)
```

So, in your case, this will do the trick

```
reduce(hcat, phi(x, 3))
```