# How to convert a matrix to an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, julia

In [How to convert an array of array into a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673412/how-to-convert-an-array-of-array-into-a-matrix) we learned how to convert an array of arrays to a matrix. But what about the other way around? How do we go from `input` to `output`, as shown below?

```
input = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
output = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to make a copy of the data then:

```
[input[i, :] for i in 1:size(input, 1)]
```

If you do not want to make a copy of the data you can use views:

```
[view(input, i, :) for i in 1:size(input, 1)]
```

After some thought those are alternatives using broadcasting:

```
getindex.([input], 1:size(input, 1), :)
view.([input], 1:size(input, 1), :)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer! I'll wait a day or two to accept an answer, to see if anyone else has an alternative solution, but yours really helped me already!

Comment: Woow! The last method is insanely fast (278 μs for 10^8 entries on my PC), but the `typeof` the output in this case is a bit scary `Array{SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Int64,Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}},true},1}`. Can you please elaborate a little on this?

Comment: This is an issue you have to get used to in Julia :). Outer `Array{X,1}` means that the wrapper structure is 1-dimensional array (thus a vector). Inner `SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,2},Tuple{Int64,Base.S‌​lice{Base.OneTo{Int6‌​4}}},true}` has a more complex meaning which you can check in the top of subarray.jl file (there are 5 parameters and it is too long to describe it here - the important are first two - type of data and dimensionality of resulting view). But in general you do not have to care too much. Treat it as if it were an array - you can use all operations in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I add one alternative too:

```
mapslices(x->[x], input,2)
```

Edit:

**Warning!** Now I see that `mapslices` return 3x1 matrix! (you could change it: `mapslices(x->[x], input,2)[:,1]`)

I am unsatisfied. I don't like any solution we find yet. They are too complicated (think for example how to explain it to children!).

It is also difficult to find function like `mapslices` in doc too. BTW there is non-exported `Base.vect` function which could be used instead of anonymous `x->[x]`.

I was thinking that sometimes is more clever to use **bigger hammer**. So I tried to find something with `DataFrames`

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> DataFrame(transpose(input)).columns
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
 [7, 8, 9]
```

1. unfortunately there is not `DataFrame.rows`
2. result's type is Array{**Any**,1}
3. I don't think it could be very quick

I hope Julia could get us better solution! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one looks more concise, albeit a bit slower on my end, than [Bogumił's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255155/2874779). Both are performant though. Hadn't heard about that function before (just starting on Julia)!

Comment: `I hope Julia could get us better solution! :)` - The problem isn't Julia though. I don't think an array of arrays is more efficient than a multidimensional array (given that its arrays dimensions are compatible). I want to use an array of arrays because I'm being coerced into due to an application (all calculations are done on a 2D array, but due to conditions outside my will I have to return an array of arrays).